# android alert dialog with a title, message and followed with a listview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

Is it possible to have an `AlertDialog` with a title, message and followed by a list view ?

If yes, can some one give me some sample code for the same.

Comment: Have you tried searching around on http://www.google.com or here on Stack Overflow first?

Comment: in case you don't know how to accept - "click the 'right mark' beside of answer"

Answer (score 0):

I think u r looking for :

```
 final CharSequence[] items = {"item1","item2","item3" };
  AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
  builder.setTitle("title");
  builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
    switch (item) {
    case 0:
     //handle item1
     break;
    case 1:
     //item2
     break;
    case 2:
     //item3
     break;
    default:
     break;
    }  }
  });
  AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
  alert.show();
```

Comment: Uhm... it even says so in the question title: "android alert dialog with a title, message and followed with a listview" You've provided a solution for the title and the items. But where's the message ?